# Manejo de datos MYSQL, retorna valores null

Tags: mysql, sql, table, null

Saludos estoy trabajando en un proyecto de pase de lista escolar, obtengo los datos de dos tablas "pasalista" y "alumnos" relacionadas por la clave "A_Ncontrol".
lo que pretendo obtener es una tabla con el registro general de asistencias por grupo, donde alumnos.A_grupo otorga los grupos y hago un count para cada pasalista.asistencia (que puede tener uno de los siguiente valores A,F,R,P). en este caso mi problema es lo siguiente.
Al hacer mi consulta los datos aparecen salteados y con valores null, leyendo e investigando he llegado a los siguiente.

```
 select grupo, ifnull(Asistencias,'') as ASISTENCIAS, ifnull(Faltas,'') as FALTAS, ifnull(Permisos,'') as PERMISOS, ifnull(Retardos,'') as RETARDOS
 from(
  select A_grupo as grupo,
case when asistencia = 'A' then count(asistencia) end as Asistencias,
       case when asistencia = 'F' then count(asistencia) end as Faltas,
       case when asistencia = 'P' then count(asistencia) end as Permisos,
       case when asistencia = 'R' then count(asistencia) end as Retardos
  from  pasalista inner join alumnos on pasalista.A_Ncontrol=alumnos.A_Ncontrol where pasalista.id_Materia=1 group by grupo, asistencia) as subconsulta;
```

lo cual arroja el siguiente resultado, como podemos observar actualmente los espacios vacios son null los cuales convierto a vacíos mediante el método ifnull().
lo que quisiera lograr es esa misma información alineada en tres filas "1a", "2a" y "3a" (sin los null, ni los espacios en blanco).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

creo que algo hago mal en la consulta pero no sé que es, agradezco de antemano sus aportaciones.

Comment: 2 recomendaciones:
1. usa left join en ves de inner join
2. me parece que el group by grupo, asistencia va fuera de tu inner join

Comment: solo me arroja un registro con la suma de todos los valores

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la subconsulta no es necesaria, el `GROUP BY` debes hacerlo solo de `grupo` y no de `grupo, asistencia`

```
select A_grupo as grupo,
case when asistencia = 'A' then ifnull(count(asistencia), '') end as Asistencias,
case when asistencia = 'F' then ifnull(count(asistencia), '') end as Faltas,
case when asistencia = 'P' then ifnull(count(asistencia), '') end as Permisos,
case when asistencia = 'R' then ifnull(count(asistencia), '') end as Retardos
from  pasalista 
inner join alumnos on pasalista.A_Ncontrol=alumnos.A_Ncontrol 
where pasalista.id_Materia=1 
group by grupo
```

Comment: probé tu sugerencia y no me da resultados solo arrojaba datos de tipo blob y null.
entonces modifiqué los case de la siguiente forma:
case when asistencia = 'A' then count(ifnull(asistencia,'')) end as Asistencias,

y me arroja los resultados pero sumados en un solo campo para cada grupo y los demas null, alguna sugerencia para que no aparezcan asi?

Comment: Me arroja una tabla como esto (aqui en el comentario se muestra lineal):

|1A | 37 | null | null | null |

|2A | null | null | null | 22 |

|3A | null |  5 | null | null |